# Invalid mapping file BaseMedia.mongodb.xml

Tags: symfony4, doctrine-odm, sonata-media-bundle

I have installed Sonata Media Bundle ^3.23, when installing doctrine-mongodb-bundle ^4.1, i receive the below error:

> In MappingException.php line 236
>   The mapping file vendor/sonata-project/media-bundle/src/Resources/config/doctrine/BaseMedia.mongodb.xml is invalid.

How i can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those having the same issue, i created a PR to fix this in the [bundle's github](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataMediaBundle/pull/1716)